# React Native Linking.addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, connection, deep-linking

I'm having problems listening to connection events with the Phantom wallet app. My app successfully opened the Phantom wallet, but when I pressed the "Connect" button, nothing happened. I tried to find out and discovered that `Linking.addEventListener` did not listen to the event when I pressed the "Connect" button.

Below is my code:

```js
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto'

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, Button, Linking} from 'react-native'
import nacl from 'tweetnacl'
import bs58 from 'bs58'

const BASE_URL = 'phantom://v1/'

const buildUrl = (path, params) => `${BASE_URL}${path}?${params.toString()}`

export default function App() {
    const [deeplink, setDeepLink] = useState('')
    const [dappKeyPair] = useState(nacl.box.keyPair())

    useEffect(() => {
        const initializeDeeplinks = async () => {
            const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL()
            if (initialUrl) {
                handleDeepLink({url: initialUrl})
            }
        }
        initializeDeeplinks()

        const listener = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleDeepLink)

        return () => {
            Linking.removeSubscription(listener)
        }
    }, [])

    const handleDeepLink = async ({url}) => {
        console.log('url', url)
        setDeepLink(url)
    }

    // Handle in-bound links
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!deeplink) return

        const url = new URL(deeplink)
        const params = url.searchParams

        // Handle an error response from Phantom
        if (params.get('errorCode')) {
            const error = Object.fromEntries([...params])
            const message =
                error?.errorMessage ??
                JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries([...params]), null, 2)
            Toast.show({
                type: 'error',
                text1: 'Error',
                text2: message,
            })
            console.log('error: ', message)
            return
        }

        // Handle a `connect` response from Phantom
        if (url.toString()?.includes('onConnect')) {
            console.log('connected')
            const sharedSecretDapp = nacl.box.before(
                bs58.decode(params.get('phantom_encryption_public_key')),
                dappKeyPair.secretKey,
            )
            const connectData = decryptPayload(
                params.get('data'),
                params.get('nonce'),
                sharedSecretDapp,
            )
            console.log(`connected to ${connectData.public_key.toString()}`)
        }
    }, [deeplink])

    const connect = async () => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams({
            dapp_encryption_public_key: bs58.encode(dappKeyPair.publicKey),
            cluster: 'mainnet-beta',
            app_url: 'https://www.solana.com/',
            redirect_link: 'deep_linking://onConnect',
        })
        const url = buildUrl('connect', params)
        Linking.openURL(url)
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress={connect} title='Connect'></Button>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
})
```

By the way, I have added the following code to the file android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml according to [Deep Linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) instructions:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="my_app_name" />
</intent-filter>
```

I asked AI tools but without success. Looking forward to a detailed answer. Thank!

Comment: What did you use as `my_app_name `? It must be `phantom` based on your sample code.